# Resolving this issue with Passenger

Tags: passenger, passenger-apache

`http://nodejs-resume.example.me/`

When the site loads,

```
/usr/local/dh/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:37
GLOBAL.PhusionPassenger = exports.PhusionPassenger = new EventEmitter();
^

ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/dh/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:37:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I have modified my `.htaccess` to use node 15.5.0
I am hosting with DreamHost VPS

Comment: I suggest you make the question title more specific, like “Dreamhost Passenger nodejs GLOBAL not defined”, and adding a nodejs-related tag to it. And I’m suggesting this because I also want to know the answer ASAP if anyone figures it out ;)

Answer (score 5):

I believe this error is because the uppercase `GLOBAL` alias for `global` was deprecated as of nodejs v14 (or some version near that). As warned [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216635318-Enabling-Passenger-for-Node-js):

> The version of Passenger running on DreamHost servers does not currently function with Node.js versions 14+.

you need to use a version of node **older** than v14 in order for passenger to work. I downgraded node to v13 and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Object name **GLOBAL** to **global** in the mentioned file. Then restart the web Server(eg. nginx, appache). In my case this was fixed my issue.